# How do I access unrelated models within a Django template?

Tags: django, templatetags

I want to use an app to create a menu that is easy to edit with the admin interface. Something like this:

```
class Menu_item
        name = models.CharField()
        item_url = models.URLField()
```

My template looks something like this:

> {% extends base.html %}
>
> div ID="nav"
>
> ```
>    {{ foo.navbar.? }}
> ```
>
> /div
>
> div ID="Content"
>
> ```
>    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
> ```
>
> /div

I want div#nav to contain a ul based upon the above model but just can't figure out how to accomplish this. It seems like an object_list generic view would be great but, the URL accesses the view for the model that populates div#content. Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there a way to access a generic view without a URL?

Thank you.

Comment: not sure i understand, what's the relationship to foo and navbar in your example code?

Comment: Sorry! foo is just a place holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered a solution. Inclusion Tags.

What I did was create an inclusion tag, which amounts to a simple custom template tag (django provides a shortcut for you!).

Here is what I did:

Ignore views.py - It will not be used in this case

Create a sub-directory in the app's dir called "templatetags" containing **init**.py and get_navbar.py (or whatever you want your tag to be):

```
mysite/
   navbar/
        templatetags/
            __ init__.py (without the space befire init)
            get_navbar.py
```

I changed my navbar.models to look like this:

```
from django.db import models


class Menu_choice(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Menu_item(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        navbar = models.ForeignKey(Menu_choice)
        item_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        item_desc = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

This allows me to create a Menu_choice object in the admin interface for each layer of navigation (primary, secondary, etc)

get_navbar.py looks like this:

```
from navbar.models import Menu_choice, Menu_item
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('navbar/navbar.html')
def get_navbar(navBar):
        navbar = Menu_item.objects.filter(navbar__name=navBar)
        return { "navbar": navbar }
```

(Note navBar as opposed to navbar)

Create the navbar.html template:

```
    <ul>

    {% for menu_item in navbar %}
        <li><a href="{{ menu_item.item_url }}">{{ menu_item.name }}&lt/a>&lt/li>
    {% endfor  %}
    </ul>
```

Finally, I inserted the following into my base.html:

```
{% load get_navbar %}
```

And where I want primary navigation:

```
{% get_navbar "primary" %}
```

Note: the quotes around the string you are sending to your inclusion tag are important. I spent a ridiculously lengthy bit of time trying to make it work before I figured that out.

Also a big thank you to dikamilo for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, in you view, get data from db:

```
def index(request):
    navbar = Menu_item.objects.all()
    return render_to_response( 'you_template.html', 
        { 'navbar': navbar }, context_instance = RequestContext (request ) )
```

And in template:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    {% for i in navbar %}
        <li><a href="{{ i.item_url }}">{{ i.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor  %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am receiving an error with this view function from the shell (and no items are rendered). Does it require a context processor? Also, the main content block is rendered by a generic view.

Comment: What kind of error ? I think you don't have "from django.shortcuts import render_to_response".